# Is it possible to use ItemLoaders for parsing HTML nodes?

Tags: python, scrapy

Normally, the item loader extracts data automatically before passing the values to the input processor:

> 1. Data from xpath1 is extracted, and passed through the input processor of the name field. ([Scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#input-and-output-processors))

Is it possible to change this behaviour for certain elements of an item loader, so I can pass in a more complicated structure (in my opinion the selector)?

I have a HTML document like this:

```
<a class="foo" href="http://example.com">example 1</a>
<a class="foo" href="http://example.org">example 2</a>
```

And now I'd like to fetch these link elements in a spider

```
loader.add_css('links', '.foo')
```

and parse them in the item loader to get a list of values (after the output processor) like this:

```
[("http://example.com", "example 1"), ("http://example.org", "example 2")]
```

However, as item loaders do convert the input automatically to unicode, this does not seem so easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.add_value()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.ItemLoader.add_value) and "manually" construct a list of `text`s and `href`s:

```
links = [(item.css('::text').extract()[0], 
          item.css('::attr(href)').extract()[0])
         for item in response.css('.foo')]
loader.add_value('links', links)
```

Comment: Was wondering, would there be a way to process that with Scrapys input input processor?